# The Preview service has been disabled until further notice. Configure local builds and use "ns run " instead when running ns preview on Svelte Native

Tags: nativescript, svelte-native

I'm new to Svelte Native. I was following the [Quick Start steps on docs](https://svelte-native.technology/docs#quick-start). Installing `nativescript` and creating the new Svelte-Native app with `npx degit halfnelson/svelte-native-template myapp` were no issue.

[image]

But, after I've `cd myapp` and then ran `ns preview` (immediate continuation of the screenshot above):

[image]

**Note**: I did **`tns`**`preview` on the second attempt because I saw that on the [screenshot on the docs](https://svelte-native.technology/docs#quick-start), just to test it out and see whether it will work (but it didn't, too).

So should I just wait 'til the Preview service has been enabled? If not, I don't know how to **configure local builds and use "ns run " instead**. How will I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also posted an issue about this [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9571#issuecomment-926541931). And thankfully, the NativeScript team answered my question. I'd like to post this here in case anyone runs into same trouble.

> The Playground and the Preview app has been disabled until further
> notice, the implementation is in progress for a better user
> experience.
>
> With `ns run` you can deploy your app to your iOS/Android device or
> simulator. To configure your local builds you should **install Xcode
> or install Android Studio**.
>
> You can read more info on the [Environment Setup](https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html).

Once you have Xcode installed, you can do this:

`ns run ios`

Or on AndroidStudio:

`ns run android`

Comment: this answer is from last year, if it is still not working why the app is available in play store ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the solution. Yet, `ns run android` is giving this, unfortunately.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaDs7.png)

Comment: Have you installed XCode? As properly instructed above before running the command?